# How to click on a button to make a program wait

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My code is like this:↓

```
JButton button = new JButton("TEXT");
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        object.wait();
    }
}
```

When I click on this button, the window is dead and I have to terminate the program in task manager...

<del>So...basically can I add a object.wait() in mouselistener?</del>

Thank you all!

Then, if I run my GUI on a separate thread, how to make the program...(I'm sorry I self-studied the multi-thread part of JAVA so I'm a little bit confused right now)

1.when I click on a button, it will pause and wait for my input in GUI

2.when I click on another button, the program continues...

Comment: Maybe [look-up what `Object.wait()` actually does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)... ;)

Comment: Read the documentation... `Object.wait` does not make the program *sleep*. Likely you want to use `Thread.sleep` instead.

Comment: You should run your GUI on a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

> when I click on a button, it will pause and wait for my input in GUI

Use a JOptionPane (or a modal JDialog) to get user input. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.